# Recursion functions, To Display dynamic menus with parent, children and siblings only

Tags: php, mysql, function, recursion

I need Help in displaying menus from database.
here is array result from database table:

```
global $menuItems;
$menuItems = array(
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 
    'Main Menu 1',
    'main' => 1,
    'parent_id' => null
],
['id' => 9,'name' => 'Main Menu 2','main' => 1,'parent_id' => null],
['id' => 10,'name' => 'Main Menu 3','main' => 1,'parent_id' => null],
['id' => 11,'name' => 'Sub Menu 1.1','main' => null,'parent_id' => 1],
['id' => 12,'name' => 'Sub Menu  1.2','main' => null,'parent_id' => 1],
['id' => 13,'name' => 'Sub Menu 1.3','main' => null,'parent_id' => 1],
['id' => 14,'name' => 'Sub Menu 1.2.1','main' => null,'parent_id' => 12],
['id' => 15,'name' => 'Sub Menu  1.2.1','main' => null,'parent_id' => 12],
['id' => 16,'name' => 'Sub Menu 3.1','main' => null,'parent_id' => 10,],
['id' => 17,'name' => 'Sub Menu 3.2','main' => null,'parent_id' => 10],
['id' => 18,'name' => 'Sub Menu 3.2.1','main' => null,'parent_id' => 17],
['id' => 19,'name' => 'Sub Menu 3.2.2','main' => null,'parent_id' => 17] );
```

I have successfully developed menu tree from following code:

```
foreach ($menuItems as $menu) {
  $parentsIds[$menu['id']] = $menu['parent_id'];
}
function parseAndPrintTree($root, $tree) {
     global $menuItems;
     $return = array();
     if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($tree as $child => $parent) {
          if($parent == $root) {                    
            unset($tree[$child]);
            foreach ($menuItems as $row) {
                if($row['id'] == $child)
             echo "<li><a href='?menu=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']. </a>";
            }    
            parseAndPrintTree($child, $tree);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}

parseAndPrintTree(0,$parentsIds);
```

It prints desired output.

[image]

What i need is every time a menu clicked,

1. All its children (if having more children that should not be printed till clicked)
2. All its siblings
3. And its parent back to root `parent_id=0`

will "only" be printed on screen along with other main menus whose parent_id is 0 (not their children).

I need following output to be produced.(steps).

On first step1:

[image]

When Clicked on "Main Menu 1":

[image]

When clicked on "Sub Menu 1.2":

[image]

When Clicked on "Main Menu 3"

[image]

When Clicked on "Sub Menu 3.2"

[image]

I am passing `?menu={$row['id']}` for getting parents  and childes, but can't figure out how to handle all siblings, parents and children.

I have tried comparing `$_GET['menu']`  id in loop with a separate function which prints okay with only one level, but when tree goes second level in depth, its first parent(back to root) is not going to be printed.

I need this only in PHP not with jQuery, Css(classes). Because I don't want to **print** other menus on screen not just hide them.

Comment: Not sure why you added the tag "mysql", but anyway: add to your array the full path to the parent and to the node itself (e.g. by running a recursion on it first). Only display a node (and only recurse down) if a node starts with that value start with the value of your selected node. If you select e.g. 3.2.1, your node value would be "3.2.1" and the parent value would be "3.2". Now display only nodes where your selected node-value will start with the parent-value of your tested node (e.g. 3.1's parent-path is "3", "3.2.1" start with "3" so its fine."3.1.2"'s parent ="3.1" is not in "3.2.1")

Comment: I have written example of menu, actually this will be used for categories. its child categories and so on, so If i add full path to parent then, when ever that category will be deleted, I have to update its path too. So I am finding this with recursion if possible which will solve problem and save that complexity too.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said you can do this recursively first. Run it once to update your paths (every time or only after changes), then do another recursion to display it. You will unfortunately not be able to work with just one recursion alone if you want to use recursion. You can of course write a function to test if the parent of the node has your dest node as a child, but this works as a recursion and is slower (runs more often). If you actually use a database, you may be able to use nested sets (they will basically provide the path for you), but siblings may still be problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have said that you want the code to be in php rather than JS Jquery. I have tried this. It iterates your array thrice, within which it built's a nested tree ie., what you needed.

Define your array **$menuItems** here and go on with the code below

```
<ul>
<?php
    foreach($menuItems as $menu)
    {
        if($menu['main'] == 1)
        {
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href='<?= '?activeMenu='.$menu['id'] ?>'><?php echo $menu['name']; ?></a>
            <?php
            if(isset($_GET['activeMenu']) && $_GET['activeMenu'] == $menu['id'])
            {
            ?>
                <ul>
                <?php
                foreach($menuItems as $submenu_level1)
                {
                    if($submenu_level1['parent_id'] == $_GET['activeMenu'])
                    {
                    ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href='<?= '?activeMenu='.$_GET['activeMenu'].'&activeSubMenu='.$submenu_level1['id'] ?>'><?php echo $submenu_level1['name']; ?>
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_GET['activeMenu']) && isset($_GET['activeSubMenu']) && $_GET['activeMenu'] == $menu['id'] && $_GET['activeSubMenu'] == $submenu_level1['id'])
                            {
                                foreach($menuItems as $submenu_level2)
                                {       
                                ?>
                                    <ul>
                                    <?php
                                        if($submenu_level2['parent_id'] == $_GET['activeSubMenu'])
                                        {
                                    ?>
                                            <li><a href='<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>'><?php echo $submenu_level2['name']; ?></li>
                                    <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
                </ul>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </li>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works two levels correctly, when I click on Sub Menu 1.2 it shows correctly Sub Menu 1.2.1 & Sub Menu 1.2.2 (in other words children of Sub Menu Second level). But when I add another level i.e Child menu of Sub Menu 1.2.2 as Sub Menu 1.2.2.A . in **$menuItems**  
`['id' => 20,'name' => 'Sub Menu  1.2.2.A','main' => null,'parent_id' => 15]`
(an other child level).
It does not iterate to the bottom, apparently loop is third level to down. I need something recursive type that does not bound in bottom levels if possible.

Comment: For anyone reaching here; though it was not clear answer for me, but it help me to solve my problem, what I did actually is, I limit children to 5 level down and implemented Vijay Wilson's solution.